# how to make dynamic javascript array with key and value group

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am integrating `jqbarGraph`, the demo worked fine. I want to make the values dynamic.

this is my json response

{"success":false,"message":{"12":7887,"11":159}}

I need an array like this

```
graphByMonth = new Array(
    [7887,12],
    [159,11]
);
```

Need to create dynamic array from JSON data.

Comment: We can't help you. You haven't asked any question here, just stated a requirement without giving us any information about your "JSON" data. You've given us required output, but no sample input. As far as we know, the numbers in your sample required output are random.

Comment: How is your example dynamic? It's a hardcoded array.

Comment: hello @hofan41,
the input is from json (object 'message'),  i crated graphByMonth array, its an demo
i need the graphByMonth is dyanamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
var graphByMonth = [],
    jsonResponse = {"success":false,"message":{"12":7887,"11":159}},
    data = jsonResponse.message;
Object.keys(data).forEach(function (k, i ) {
    graphByMonth.push([data[k],+k]);
});
console.log(graphByMonth);
```

Comment: thanks @Niranjan Borawake, its worked fine